# SQL query to count all after left join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with users, a table with news articles and a table of reactions that says user X has liked/disliked article Y. The query I have now (which is working fine) selects all articles and returns the like state of a specific user on each article (none if user has neither liked or disliked). I'm trying to modify this query so that it can also count the total amount of likes on the article, not just by the specific user.

Current query:

```
 SELECT R.articleID, N.title, N.content, COALESCE (R.state, 'none') AS state
 FROM News N
 LEFT JOIN Reaction R on N.ID = R.articleid and R.personid = 1;
```

Additionally you can find all the tables and fields [here](https://rextester.com/GTJR95174).

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [expected result](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) based on your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform a subquery for that. I imagine that it will look something like this:

```
 SELECT R.articleID, N.title, N.content, COALESCE (R.state, 'none') AS state,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM News INNER JOIN Reaction on News.ID = Reaction.articleid where News.id=N.id) as TotalCount
 FROM News N
 LEFT JOIN Reaction R on N.ID = R.articleid and R.personid = 1;
```

Comment: This works but why do you need both an `ON` and a `WHERE` in the subquery? Also from a complexity POV, doesn't this do a on every single row? I imagined there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: You could have SELECT COUNT(1) FROM News INNER JOIN Reaction on Reaction.articleid =N.id but I like to use WHERE to filter and ON to link. Regardless it will not change anything performance wise. Just a matter of syntax

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend aggregation:

```
SELECT n.ID as articleID, n.title, n.content,
       COALESCE(MAX(r.state) FILTER (WHERE r.personid = 1), 'no state') as person_state,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE r.state = 'like') as num_likes,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE r.state = 'dislike') as num_dislikes
FROM News n LEFT JOIN
     Reaction r 
     ON n.ID = r.articleid
GROUP BY n.ID, n.title, n.content;
```

Note that `FILTER` is part of standard SQL for representing conditional aggregation -- and Postgres supports this syntax.  It can be replaced by equivalent `CASE` constructs.

Comment: This changes the existing behavior a little, `person_state` has null values which I avoided using `COALESCE`

Comment: @ninesalt . . . So add the `COALESCE()`.